# How to update python variables with f2py

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I'm trying to create a python program that uses fortran to do some calculations, but I'm struggling to update the variables values with the subroutines.
To give a simple example of what I mean, I have a python script `r.py`:

```py
import fortran_script
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10, 20, 30], np.float32)
b = 10
fortran_script.fmodule.r(a, b)
print(f"a = {a}")
print(f"b = {b}")
```

and a fortran script `r.f90`:

```
module fmodule
      implicit none
contains
      subroutine r(a, b)
      real, intent(inout):: a(:)
      integer, intent(inout) :: b
      a(1:3)=a(3:1:-1)
      b=b+10
      write(*,*) 'a = ', a
      write(*,*) 'b = ', b
      end subroutine r
end module fmodule
```

Compiling the fortran script with `f2py` and running the python code, the fortran writed the correct values:

```bash
 a =    30.0000000       20.0000000       10.0000000    
 b =           20
```

but python didn't get the correct values of the integer `b`:

```
a = [30. 20. 10.]
b = 10
```

So, my question is how do I properly pass and return values from a fortran subroutine to python with f2py?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass b also as a numpy array to get back its value.

Comment: Welcome. That is probably correct, but could you explain it more or show an example? I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [answer]. Note that there was already a much more comprehensive answer along these lines but the author deleted it probaably because it received a downvote.